# How to change format of data to '%Y%m%d' in Pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, date, series

I have a DF with first column showing as e.g. `2018-01-31 00:00:00`.

I want to convert whole column (or during printing / saving to other variable) that date to `20180131` format. 
NOT looking to do that during saving to a CSV file.

Tried this but it did not work:

`df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], format='%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 6):

[`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) is used to convert your series to `datetime`:

```
s = pd.Series(['2018-01-31 00:00:00'])
s = pd.to_datetime(s)

print(s)

0   2018-01-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

[`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) converts your `datetime` series to a string in your desired format:

```
s = s.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

print(s)

0    20180131
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

`pd.to_datetime` will convert a string to a date. You want to [covert a date to a string](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

```
df['mydate'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Note that it's possible your date is already a string, but in the wrong format in which case you might have to convert it to a date first:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: What is `.dt`? What libraries you are importing?

Comment: No libraries, those are date functions built into pandas. Follow the link in the post.

Comment: This did not work for me: `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Comment: what is `df['mydate'].dtype`?

Comment: @Joe Then `pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')` will work. Certainly for your example date.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string column with 2018-01-31 00:00:00. to a datetime:

```
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'])

#Get your preferred strings based on format:

df['mydate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#Output: '2018-01-31'

df['mydate'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
#output:'20180131'
```